# Azure File Share attached drive is not visible/accessible from SSMS or SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server, azure

In our DB migration project we need to migrate data from a SQL Server DB which are used by Desktop application installed in our clients location. For that we have implemented a desktop tool which takes backup and uploads it to Blob storage which is attached as local drive (mounting S: using net use command) in the Azure windows and later at the server end we need to attach this backup file to sql server (and rest of the ETL process goes).

We have created SSIS package which does this DB attachment using running ATTACH DB command in master DB. When we manually run the SSIS PACKAGE, there is no issue. But the same thing is failing when this package is invoked from SQL AGENT JOB. Following is the command I am running from SSMS

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDB FROM DISK='S:\backup.BAK'
```

Error:

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot open backup device
>   'S:\backup.BAK'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path
>   specified.). Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 RESTORE DATABASE is
>   terminating abnormally.

Don't know what issue this is. Can some one help me understand why I am unable to access Azure storage drive from SSMS?

Comment: Why not upload your file to Azure File Share. You could mount file share directly. You could not mount blob, I guess it is the reason that SSIS could not access it.

Comment: actually, its file share. I have mounted using `net use S: \\xxxx.FILE.CORE.WINDOWS.NET\container /u:user key

Comment: Could you mkdir file or delete file on driver S?

Comment: Yes, all from command line

Comment: @Walter-MSFT I have updated OP. Retore db command should work right?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the SQL Agent service account does not have the access to Shared drive. Check your user and drive permissions.